# How do you find range of values for a discontinuous function?

Tags: functions

Suppose I define the following function:

$$
F(x) = 1 + x \text{  for } x\in (-1, 0], 1-x \text{  for } x \in (0, 1] \text{ and } 0 \text{ 
 otherwise}
$$

And I want to find the range of values where $F(x) \geq F(x+1)$ and where $F(x) \geq 1 - F(x) - F(x+1)$.

How do I go about doing this?

I tried a graphical approach wherein I plot the curves but I ended up getting confused around how does the $F(x+1)$ term works over here.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Graphical approach would work fine.

Let $G(x)=F(x+1)$ and replace as such in your expressions so you don't get confused.

$G(x) = x+2 \hspace{70pt}$ for $x+1 \in (-1, 0],$ i.e. $x \in (-2,1]$ 
$G(x) = 1-(x+1)=-x \hspace{18pt}$  for $x+1 \in (0,1],$ i.e. $x \in (-1,0]$ 
$G(x) = 0 \hspace{89pt}$ otherwise

Comment: And then how do I go about finding the range of values where $F(x)≥F(x+1)$ and where $F(x)≥1−F(x)−F(x+1)$?

Comment: "Graphical" Approach as you said: Draw the individual graphs, add/subtract them and compare them

Answer (score 0):

The function $F$ is not discontinuous... In the picture you can see the graphics of $F(x)$ (blue) and $F(x+1)$ (Orange).[image]

So, for instance, $F(x)\ge F(x+1)$ if and only if $x \ge -\frac 12$ or $x\leq -2$. Below you can find the graphics of $F(x)+F(x+1)$ and $1-F(x)-F(x+1)$.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks @PierreCarre. A couple of follow up questions:
1. How do I find the range of values where $F(x)≥1−F(x)−F(x+1)$? 

2. How does this work algebraically?

Comment: @JashShah algebraically, you can just obtain the expression of $1-F(x)-F(x+1)$ on each interval of interest and solve the corresponding  inequality on each of those intervals.

Comment: what would the graph for $1−F(x)−F(x+1)$ look like?